# How to delete storage in 'Other Volumes in Container'?

Tags: disk-utility, storage, disk-volume

[image]

As you can tell from the picture I have the majority of my disk storage being taken up by 'Other Volumes in Container' leaving me with less than 20GB to actually use. Running Mojave 10.14.2 on a 2015 Macbook Pro

Here are the fixes I have attempted:

- Contacted Apple support, it has been 2 weeks and they have been unable to fix it
- Wiped disk and reinstalled OS. Note: the 97GB of 'Other volumes in Container' still remains after the disk wipe and before the reinstall of OS
- Turned network caching on and off
- Used Omnidisksweeper
- Searched in activity monitor for any suspicious activities as well as running an antivirus scan
- reindexing spotlight
- ran diskutil list in terminal and it shows Preboot, Recovery and VM only taking up approximately 2GB

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem too, I solved by this step

```
diskutil list

    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.0 GB   disk0s2

   /dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume 未命名 - 数据           93.1 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 82.4 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.3 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume mac - Data              13.7 GB    disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume mac                     11.3 GB    disk1s6
   7:                APFS Volume Untitled                487.4 KB   disk1s7

   /dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Fonedog-PowerMyma-1... +162.5 MB   disk2

   /dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            OmniDiskSweeper        +25.2 MB    disk3
```

then delete the 93.1 GB    disk1s1

```
diskutil eraseVolume APFS Blank /dev/disk1s1
```

all done

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and I have an inelegant solution. I had 56GB of space used up out of 128GB at one point on my 2017 MacBook Pro, so I know your pain.

1) Back up to time machine. 
2) Reformat your hard drive to the old Mac files system (not AFPS, that won’t work)
3) Check your HD - does it still have the 98GB? It shouldn’t.
4) Reformat to AFPS (yep)
5) Run Time Machine

This wiped the whole ‘container’ issue for me, although now there is still a manageable 4GB, which I assume is just time machine snapshots. I consider this fixed.

Hope that helps. If it does, spread the word and get Mac to fix this issue.